# Collision detection of two objects in Android

Tags: android, collision-detection, android-canvas

I have already posted a question about this topic..but did not get the answer.I am doing a game.in that app i have to detect the collition of two objects in a canvas. The object class is pasted here.

```
     public class Droid {

private Bitmap bitmap;  // the actual bitmap
private int x;          // the X coordinate
private int y;          // the Y coordinate
private boolean touched;    // if droid is touched/picked up
private Speed speed;    // the speed with its directions

public Droid(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = new Speed();
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}
public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public boolean isTouched() {
    return touched;
}

public void setTouched(boolean touched) {
    this.touched = touched;
}

public Speed getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

public void setSpeed(Speed speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}


public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x - (bitmap.getWidth() / 2), y - (bitmap.getHeight() / 2), null);
}

/**
 * Method which updates the droid's internal state every tick
 */
public void update() {
    if (!touched) {
        x += (speed.getXv() * speed.getxDirection()); 
        y += (speed.getYv() * speed.getyDirection());
    }
}


/**
 * Handles the {@link MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN} event. If the event happens on the 
 * bitmap surface then the touched state is set to <code>true</code> otherwise to <code>false</code>
 * @param eventX - the event's X coordinate
 * @param eventY - the event's Y coordinate
 */
public void handleActionDown(int eventX, int eventY) {
    if (eventX >= (x - bitmap.getWidth() / 2) && (eventX <= (x + bitmap.getWidth()/2))) {
        if (eventY >= (y - bitmap.getHeight() / 2) && (y <= (y + bitmap.getHeight() / 2))) {
            // droid touched
            setTouched(true);
        } else {
            setTouched(false);
        }
    } else {
        setTouched(false);
    }

}
}
```

I am creating 5 droid objects. 4 of them are continually moving on the canvas, and 1 is controlled by the user. I want to detect the event in which those 4 moving objects collide with user-controlled object. I have read many tutorials but not yet got a solution.please anybody help me...

Comment: nobody have answer for this question?????? :(

Comment: It would be better to use AndEngine for gaming.

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler to use AndEngine and let it simplify these tasks for you.

- [Collision detection example](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/CollisionDetectionExample.java)
- [Pixel perfect collision detection](https://github.com/m5/andengine-pixel-perfect) - ([related article](http://micah5.com/2011/05/30/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-for-andengine.html))

Answer (score 1):

In general, simplifying the collision detection by using an imprecise representation is generally a good idea, since it is easy to work with and implement, and the speed is generally fine. For such a solution, collision detection with axis-aligned bounding boxes, or possibly circles, should work fine. For more complicated solutions, polygon-based solutions are available, but they are harder to use.

If you need more precise collision detection, such as detecting collisions between two images, you need pixel-perfect collision detection. This is generally really hard to do efficiently, so using an existing library is recommended.

Since you work with Java, and you seem to use a bitmap, [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) as Reno recommended or [PoxelColl](https://github.com/Poxelcoll/Poxelcoll) should do the trick. If you need basic transformations like rotation and scaling, I recommend PoxelColl.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a library that provides functionality for detecting sprite collisions. Try googling "android sprite collision".